# How to use the chr function inside a regular expression in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, chr

I have a Perl script which has a string which may or may not contain character 146 in the ASCII character codes. I'm interested in using the chr() function inside a regular expression to find out if that string really does contain that character. If the character is there, I would like to substitute it with a "'" character.

Is this possible? If not what's another way to do this?

This one has my stumped. Thanks!

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading. This is not so much about using chr() in regex but about using special characters in regex.

Comment: Character 146 is not ASCII.  ASCII stops at 127.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can substitute variables into patterns:

```
$c = chr(146);
$target =~ s/$c/'/go; # "o" means $c won't change so remember it
```

but usually you would specify it as a literal by converting it to octal or hex:

```
$target =~ s/\222/'/g; # octal
$target =~ s/\x92/'/g; # hex
```